# iOS Camera Video Live Preview Is Offset To Picture Taken

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uikit, avfoundation

I am working with the camera.

The camera presents as a live feed to the user and when they click an image is created and passed to the user.

The problem is the image is designed to go to the top most position, which is higher than the live preview is showing.

Do you know how to adjust the frame of the camera so the top of the live video feed matches the top of the picture they are going to take?

I thought this could would do that, but it doesn't. Here is my current camera frame code:

```
 //Add the device to the session, get the video feed it produces and add it to the video feed layer
    func initSessionFeed()
    {
_session = AVCaptureSession()
        _session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
        updateVideoFeed()

        _videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: _session)
        _videoPreviewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.frame.width, self.frame.width) //the live footage IN the video feed view
        _videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        self.layer.addSublayer(_videoPreviewLayer)//add the footage from the device to the video feed layer
    }

    func initOutputCapture()
    {
        //set up output settings
        _stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        var outputSettings:Dictionary = [AVVideoCodecJPEG:AVVideoCodecKey]
        _stillImageOutput.outputSettings = outputSettings
        _session.addOutput(_stillImageOutput)
        _session.startRunning()
    }

    func configureDevice()
    {
        if _currentDevice != nil
        {
            _currentDevice.lockForConfiguration(nil)
            _currentDevice.focusMode = .Locked
            _currentDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
    }

    func captureImage(callback:(iImage)->Void)
    {
        if(_captureInProcess == true)
        {
            return
        }
        _captureInProcess = true

        var videoConnection:AVCaptureConnection!
        for connection in _stillImageOutput.connections
        {
            for port in (connection as AVCaptureConnection).inputPorts
            {
                if (port as AVCaptureInputPort).mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo
                {
                    videoConnection = connection as AVCaptureConnection
                    break;
                }

                if videoConnection != nil
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if videoConnection  != nil
        {
            _stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection)
            {
                (imageSampleBuffer : CMSampleBuffer!, _) in
                let imageDataJpeg = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageSampleBuffer)
                var pickedImage = UIImage(data: imageDataJpeg, scale: 1)
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(pickedImage.size, false, pickedImage.scale)
                pickedImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, pickedImage.size.width, pickedImage.size.height))
                pickedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() //this returns a normalized image
                if(self._currentDevice == self._frontCamera)
                {
                    var context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
                    pickedImage = UIImage(CGImage: pickedImage.CGImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: .UpMirrored)
                    pickedImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, pickedImage.size.width, pickedImage.size.height))
                    pickedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                }
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                var image:iImage = iImage(uiimage: pickedImage)
                self._captureInProcess = false
                callback(image)
            }
        }
    }
```

If I adjust the fame of the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer by say, raising the y value, I just get a black bar showing the offset amount. Im very curious as to why the top most of the video frame is not matching my output image.

I did 'crop' the camera so its a perfect square, but then why is top of the live camera feed not what the actual top is (as the image defaults to a much higher position the camera feed does not show)

Update:

Here is the before and after screen shots of what I am talking about

Before:
[Before image](http://postimg.org/image/qsjdokxan/)  This is what the live feed is showing

After:
[After image](http://postimg.org/image/wnwyepgpz/) This is what the resultant image is when the user clicks take photo

Comment: So you want the result image to go to the top of the screen, which looks exactly what you see in the live feed?

Comment: I want the camera feed (the before) to look like what it delivers to the user when they take a photo (the after).

Comment: Fantastic AV camera sample code: http://drivecurrent.com/devops/using-swift-and-avfoundation-to-create-a-custom-camera-view-for-an-ios-app/#comment-4686

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
_videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

you could try

```
_videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
```

In general, the preview and the captured image width and height will have to match. You might have to do more "cropping" on the preview or on the final image, or both.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this code works for me:

```
previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
var bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

previewLayer?.bounds = bounds
previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize
previewLayer?.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds))
self.cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
captureSession.startRunning()
```