# AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhoto - result is offset/jumped down compared to preview

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm using [`AVCapturePhotoOutput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput) to take photos with the camera. However, the photo that's taken is sometimes (~50% of the time) slightly offset downwards, as compared to the preview video feed.

Here's how I'm setting up the video feed:

```
let avSession = AVCaptureSession()
let photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let cameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)!
    
    do {
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice)
        if avSession.canAddInput(captureDeviceInput) {
            avSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            avSession.sessionPreset = .photo
        }
        if avSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {
            avSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
    
    previewView.videoPreviewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
    previewView.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    previewView.session = self.avSession
    
    avSession.startRunning() /// start the session
    outputImageView.alpha = 0 /// hide image view
}
```

This produces a live video preview, as expected. Next, I use [`capturePhoto(with:delegate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput/1648765-capturephoto) to take photos:

```
let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
if let photoPreviewType = photoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first {
    photoSettings.previewPhotoFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: photoPreviewType]
    photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
}
```

```
/// get the image from `capturePhoto`
extension ViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
            let previewImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
            outputImageView.image = previewImage
            outputImageView.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}
```

And the result ([video version here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49819455/121827614-8fbf9400-cc71-11eb-9157-667a1e1f171d.MOV)):

[image: Image jumps down when Capture button pressed]

How can I get rid of this offset? I expect the photo from `capturePhoto` to be match the video feed as closely as possible. I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26447180/14351818) which seems like a similar problem, but it's over 6 years old and the solutions didn't work.

[Full demo project of the problem](https://github.com/aheze/CapturePhotoOffset)

Comment: @Tyler viewDidLoad only.